# Constraint Qualification for Lagrangian Method

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization, lagrange-multiplier

I am trying to solve the problem $\max_{x,y} f(x,y)=2x^3-3x^2 \textrm{ s.t. } g(x,y)=(3-x)^3-y^2=0$ where both $f(x,y)$ and $g(x,y)$ are defined on $\mathbb{R}^2$. I would like to know if the following solution is logically sound.

From the first- and second-order conditions for $f(x,y)$, a local maximum and local minimum exist for $f(x,y)$ at $x=0$ and $x=1$ respectively. Based on the constraint, since $y^2\geq0$, $(3-x)^3 \geq 0$ and therefore $x\leq 3$. We shall then check the boundary point, stationary points and limit to infinity for $x\leq 3$. Because $\lim_{x \to -\infty} f(x,y) = -\infty$, $f(0,y)=0$, $f(2,y)=-1$ and $f(3,y)=27$, $(x,y)=(3,0)$ must maximize $f(x,y)$.

I also notice that the Lagrange method for this problem does not work because it fails the constraint qualification. In particular, the first-order conditions for $L=2x^3-3x^2-\lambda[(3-x)^3-y^2]$ are $\frac{\partial L}{\partial x}=6x^2+3\lambda(3-x)^2=0$ and $\frac{\partial L}{\partial y}=-6y+2\lambda y=0$, and yield no solution. In that case, is checking the points that fail the constraint qualification ($\nabla g(x^*,y^*) \neq (0,0))$ the only way to solve the problem?

Comment: I assume it should be $f(x,y)=2x^3-3y^2$? While you may not need Lagrange Multiplier method to solve this problem, I do not think it fails. It gives you critical point $(3, 0)$. If you see the graph of the constraint, it becomes clear too.

Comment: The objective function is $f(x,y)=2x^3-3x^2$, not $f(x,y)=2x^3-3y^2$, in which case does the problem still make sense? A software I used gives the same maximum point $(3,0)$.

Comment: Then your working has mistakes. How did you get $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}=-6y+2\lambda y=0$?

Comment: Anyway the problem does not make sense. How is it $f(x, y)$ when it is not a function of $y$?

Comment: Updated to reflect the error. Taking the objective function to be $f(x)=2x^3-3x^2$ instead, does it make sense to subject it to the constraint $g(x,y)$?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming $f(x,y) = 2x^3-3y^2$, the Lagrange method of multipliers is based on regularity to the point of non null gradient existence in the involved functions. This method relies on the possibility of tangency between the objective function level surfaces and the restriction. Those points when they exist are called stationary points. In the present case we have

$$
\cases{
\nabla f = (6x^2,-6y,0)\\
\nabla g = (-3(3-x)^2,-2 y,0)
}
$$

making now $\nabla f\times\nabla g = (0,0,108x y-162 y-30 x^2 y)$ we can verify that the only point in which $\nabla f = \lambda \nabla g$ is at $y=0$ but at this point $\nabla g=(0,0,0)$ which invalidates the method. Resuming: the method doesn't fail, because it can't be applied here.

NOTE

If $f(x,y) = 2x^3-3x^2$ then

$$
\nabla f\times\nabla g = (0,0,-12x(x-1)y)
$$

and we have linear dependency at $x = 0, x = -1, y = 0$. If $y = 0$ then $\nabla g=(0,0,0)$ and if $x=0$ or $x = 1$ we have $\nabla f=(0,0,0)$